# Get dependent records from table

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the table structure. I want to fetch all the `id_product` which have value 2 and 601(here `id_product` = `5`). If i use `OR` all the records will be populated which is not necessary.

```
     id_product    attribute_id  Value
        5               2         2
        6               2         2
        8               2         601
        6               2         601
        5               3         601
        8               3         32
        6               3         41
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I don't want to use sub query :-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a group by query:

```
select
  id_product
from
  tablename
where
  attribute_id=2 and values in (2,601)
group by
  id_product
having
  count(*)=2
```

this will select all products that have (attribute_id=2 and value=2) or (attribute_id=2 and value=601) in two different rows, and then it will count the number of rows returned and select only products that have two rows (one with value 2 and one with value 601).

Another option (it's not too clear from your question) is to use this where clause instead of the one on the query above:

```
where
  (attribute_id=2 and value=2) or
  (attribute_id=3 and value=601)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM nameTable WHERE Values IN (2,601) and attribute_id = 2
```

Comment: no it will return 5,8,6 but only 5 has 2. so i need only 5

Comment: how would u know id_product? i have to fetch it. and i don't want to use subquery